# PolarProxy generates a SAN cert generating a curl error

Tags: proxy, curl

I ran curl 7.58.0 (see version in [attached pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmfxn.png)) with -v and got a result indicating the CN=example.com in the cert was OK, but that curl couldn’t find a matching subjectAltName. Is there a switch or param to disable this checking, or should I assume the issue is with the PolarProxy (tried to install from [this page](https://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2019-12&post=Installing-a-Fake-Internet-with-INetSim-and-PolarProxy)). It does work with the -k/--insecure flag. I was running through the steps to install inetsim and PolarProxy to do malware analysis. My remote clients also can’t connect over https or smtps, so I’m trying to unravel the error seen in this screenshot. This is ubuntu server 18.04.

```
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):

* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):

* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):

* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):

* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):

* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):

* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):

* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):

* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol

* Server certificate:

*  subject: CN=example.com

*  start date: Jul  2 20:44:34 2022 GMT

*  expire date: Jul  3 20:44:34 2023 GMT

*  subjectAltName does not match example.com

* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'example.com'

* Closing connection 0

* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):

* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):

curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'example.com'

More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

From what I could tell on a remote client, the cert is generated by PolarProxy with a `'Subject Alternative Name' = 'DNS Name=CN=example.com'` which to me doesn't look legit and curl seems to be objecting.

There seem to be no switches on the PolarProxy executable to suppress generation of the bogus (I think) SAN element in the x509 certificate.

Anybody that has experience in PolarProxy and might let me know what's going on, please do so. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: IIRC all certificates must have a SAN list nowadays (or so the CA Forum says).

Comment: @DanielB That's correct - while the RFC has always discouraged using the CN for hostnames/IPs, instead recommending the utilization of SAN profiles due to exploit potential, and in conjunction with web browsers discontinuing Trust for certificates without SANs a couple years ago, all certs are required to have SANs _(it's simply laziness to issue a cert with a CN and not a SAN profile, as it takes less than a minute to configure one)_.

Comment: @JW0914: Chrome/ium since a few years and thus Opera and new-Edge require SAN, but Firefox doesn't for private CA (as here), nor did IE before its recent demise, nor I believe Safari. (But concur it is a good idea anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incorrect Subject Alternative Name (SAN) is due to a bug introduced in version 0.9.6 of PolarProxy. It has now been fixed in version 0.9.7 thanks to your bug report. This bug only affected PolarProxy’s `--terminate` mode, in which PolarProxy doesn’t have access the domain’s original X.509 certificate. In this mode PolarProxy generates a leaf certificate from scratch instead of creating a slightly modified clone of the real certificate. As you noticed, the SAN incorrectly got set to `DNS Name=CN=example.com` instead of `DNS Name=example.com` due to this bug.

Thank you for reporting this issue @AlMo320!

Comment: Thanks Erik! I got to know a lot more about RFC 3280 and 1034 (and PolarProxy too) thanks to this regression! I hope the use of SubjName soon goes the way of the dodo, however both those RFCs are 20+ years old, like a lot of malware exploits.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no option to disable only SAN checking. For HTTPS, the SAN extension doesn't have to be present<sup>1</sup>, but if it *is* present then it always takes priority over Subject CN – at this point it's pretty much mandatory behavior for HTTPS clients (technically has been since RFC 2818 in 2000 – though still not a hard 'MUST' for other TLS-based protocols, but it's getting there too). So really PolarProxy is generating a bad certificate and `--insecure` is what you're asking for.

But I just tried PolarProxy 0.9.6.0 and I don't see the problem here – it exactly mimics the certificate that the proxy *itself* receives from an upstream server, including copying the same SAN that the real certificate had.

So if you are seeing "CN=" as part of the SAN, it's most likely that the real server's certificate is malformed as well...

---

<sup>1</sup> Certificate *issuance* policies set by the "CA/Browser Forum" that public CAs operate by already require all public HTTPS certificates to have a SAN; if I remember correctly, they even discourage putting any CN in the Subject at all.

The CA/B issuance rules don't apply to privately operated CAs (such as your MITM proxy) and web browsers usually do not enforce them for locally installed roots (non-web TLS clients are even less strict), so technically SAN remains optional for HTTPS, although it is always a good idea to stay close to the CA/B profiles.

However, certificate *validation* rules set in the HTTPS RFC still do apply regardless of CA type, so if your proxy *does* generate a SAN extension at all, then it has to be a valid SAN.

Comment: PolarProxy in this case has no upstream server *except* inetsim on p 80. The whole point of PP is to serve as a MITM. I guess to simplify the question I'm asking: is "DNS=CN=foo.bar" a *legitimate* SAN, because that's how PP is generating on-the-fly certificates, to work with inetsim's DNS resolver, web server, and SMTP server, and allow pcap and wireshark to view the malware's network calls in the clear. https://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2019-12&post=Installing-a-Fake-Internet-with-INetSim-and-PolarProxy

Comment: @AlMo320: no. dnsName entry in SAN must contain a syntactically-valid (though not necessarily assigned/resolvable) DNS name and CN=foo.bar is not that.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @dave_thompson_085. I actually see the SAN as "DNS Name=CN=foo.bar" which is also 'not that.' :)

Comment: From RFC 3280:  When the subjectAltName extension contains a domain name system
   label, the domain name MUST be stored in the dNSName (an IA5String).
   The name MUST be in the "preferred name syntax," as specified by RFC
   1034 [RFC 1034]. 

From RFC 1034 (paraphrased):
 LDAP attribute CN (Common Name) <> DNS attribute CNAME